# How to clear cache in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am making an app in Ionic 4 and Angular, I would like to clear the cache in order to not use the previous data from the page. I attempted to do:

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Cache-control', 'no-cache');
```

Does anyone happen to know how to achieve this?

Comment: can you describe in detail your context - do you want this on local machine? or when app is deployed as PWA and accessed via browser? or when you build your app code with cordova?

Comment: This is for when the app is built with cordova

Comment: still don't understand what the issue is - if you bundle your app with cordova what exactly you do such that the app "caches" previous data? can you share full context?